# May I use JsDocs to clarify Typescript Utility Types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My question is regarding the use of `jsDocs` to give more context typescript Utility Types.

**Given the example**

```
  type Split<
    S extends string, 
    D extends string, 
    T extends string[] = []
  > = 
   S extends `${infer BD}${D}${infer AD}` 
   ? Split<AD, D, [...T, BD]> 
   : [...T, S];
```

I understand that this type of code can be really tough for a beginner to read, so I was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
  /**
   * Splits a string based type into an tuple using a delimiter.
   *
   * @param S - The input string to be split.
   * @param D - The delimiter string used for splitting.
   * @param T - The resulting array of substrings.
   *
   * @example
   * // Split a comma-separated string
   * type Result = Split<"apple,banana,cherry", ",", []>;
   * // Result: ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
   */

  type Split<
    S extends string, 
    D extends string, 
    T extends string[] = []
  > = 
   S extends `${infer BD}${D}${infer AD}` 
   ? Split<AD, D, [...T, BD]> 
   : [...T, S];

  // ----
```

Is that well accepted by the community? There's any downside that it can cause?

Thanks!

Comment: No but the JSDoc won't "show up correctly" if your IDE formats each JSDoc tag differently in the tooltip. I would just use a doc comment without @-tags.

Comment: I believe the correct tag would be `@template`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the @template, I'll be using this for now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use JSDoc to document your utility types.
The correct form would look like this:

```js
 /**
   * Splits a string based type into an tuple using a delimiter.
   *
   * @template S - The input string to be split.
   * @template D - The delimiter string used for splitting.
   * @template T - The resulting array of substrings.
   *
   * @returns A tuple of strings representing the segments of the original string after being split by the delimiter.
   *
   * @example
   * // Split a comma-separated string
   * type Result = Split<"apple,banana,cherry", ",", []>;
   * // Result: ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
   */
  type Split<
    S extends string, 
    D extends string, 
    T extends string[] = []
  > = 
   S extends `${infer BD}${D}${infer AD}` 
   ? Split<AD, D, [...T, BD]> 
   : [...T, S];
```

Comment: Wow, nice one with the `@template`, didn't know it existed. Also I'd add that for such complex types it's much better to use not just letters for the type parameters, but instead use full and understandable words, like `type Split<InputString extends ..., Delimiter extends ..., ResultingSubstrings extends ...> = ...`. It may look bloated at first sigh but makes such a complex type read like a poetry

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's quite hard to balance between short x understandable. In this example I'm using short names because it's the most common thing I see the community doing, I particulary dont thing they are great for readability but with the jsDocs they became much more viable!

Comment: Well yes, single letter generics are certainly shorter - but is this really a benefit? Since modern IDEs have autocompletion, word-wrap, etc. a lot of people have stopped using single letters for generic type parameters. The convention I think is the most prominent right now is to prefix generics with `T`, e.g. `TString`, `TDelimiter` and so on

Comment: @nyarthan I always inspect the TS generics to use them as inspirations, hence the one letter generics. But I agree that they are not as much descriptive as your examples. For now on I'll give it a try! Thanks again!